# Aws cost and usage for all the instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I would like to get the usage cost report of each instance in my aws account form a period of time.

I'm able to get linked_account_id and service in the output but I need instance_id as well. Please help

```
import argparse
import boto3
import datetime

cd = boto3.client('ce', 'ap-south-1')

results = []

token = None
while True:
    if token:
        kwargs = {'NextPageToken': token}
    else:
        kwargs = {}
    data = cd.get_cost_and_usage(
    TimePeriod={'Start': '2019-01-01', 'End':  '2019-06-30'},
    Granularity='MONTHLY',
    Metrics=['BlendedCost','UnblendedCost'],
    GroupBy=[
                {'Type': 'DIMENSION', 'Key': 'LINKED_ACCOUNT'},
                {'Type': 'DIMENSION', 'Key': 'SERVICE'}
             ], **kwargs)
    results += data['ResultsByTime']
    token = data.get('NextPageToken')
    if not token:
        break
print('\t'.join(['Start_date', 'End_date', 'LinkedAccount', 'Service', 'blended_cost','unblended_cost', 'Unit', 'Estimated']))
for result_by_time in results:
    for group in result_by_time['Groups']:
        blended_cost = group['Metrics']['BlendedCost']['Amount']
        unblended_cost = group['Metrics']['UnblendedCost']['Amount']
        unit = group['Metrics']['UnblendedCost']['Unit']
        print(result_by_time['TimePeriod']['Start'], '\t',
        result_by_time['TimePeriod']['End'],'\t',
        '\t'.join(group['Keys']), '\t',
        blended_cost,'\t',
        unblended_cost, '\t',
        unit, '\t',
        result_by_time['Estimated'])
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Cost Explorer can't treat the usage per instance. There is a function *Cost and Usage Reports* which gives a detailed billing report by dump files. In this file, you can see the instance id.

It can also be connected to the *AWS Athena*. Once you did this, then directly query to the file on Athena.

---

Here is my presto example.

```
select 
    lineitem_resourceid,
    sum(lineitem_unblendedcost) as unblended_cost,
    sum(lineitem_blendedcost) as blended_cost
from 
    <table>
where 
    lineitem_productcode = 'AmazonEC2' and 
    product_operation like 'RunInstances%'
group by 
    lineitem_resourceid
```

The result is

```
lineitem_resourceid     unblended_cost      blended_cost
i-*****************     279.424             279.424
i-*****************     139.948             139.948
i-********              68.198              68.198
i-*****************     3.848               3.848
i-*****************     0.013               0.013
```

where the resourceid containes the instance id. The amount of cost is summed for all usage in this month. For other type of product_operation, it will contains different resource ids.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an individual tag to all instances (e.g. `Id`) and then group by that tag:

```
GroupBy=[
   {
       'Type': 'TAG',
       'Key': 'Id'
   },
],
```